# insert performance sort data in list and vector

Tags: c++

In the Principle and Practice book of Bjarne Stroustrup there an exercise in chapter 20 which asks to insert random value in vector and list in sort way (experiment suggested by Jhon Bentley)

this is my code (if there is a better way doing this sorry )

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;


template<typename Iter, typename T>
int find_index(Iter start, Iter end, const T& value)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (start != end)
    {
        while (start!=end && value >= *start)
        {
            ++index;
            ++start;
        }
        return index;
    }
    return -1;
}

template<typename Iter>
void print(Iter first,Iter end)
{

    while (first != end)
    {
        cout << *first << endl;
        first++;
    }
}

int generate_random(int min, int max)
{
    random_device device;
    mt19937 generator{ device() };
    uniform_int_distribution<int> d{ min,max };
    return d(generator);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 1000;

    vector<int> vec;
    list<int> list;

    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int value = generate_random(1, n);
        int index = find_index(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
        if (index == -1) vec.insert(vec.begin(), value);
        else vec.insert(vec.begin() + index, value);
    }
    auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    print(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    cout << "Time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " milliseconds" << endl;
    system("pause");

    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        int value = generate_random(1, n);
        int index = find_index(list.begin(), list.end(), value);
        if (index == -1) list.insert(list.begin(), value);
        else
        {
            auto p = list.begin();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                p++;
            }
            list.insert(p, value);
        }
    }
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    print(list.begin(), list.end());
    cout << "Time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " milliseconds" <<  endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

and the output is:

```
N     1000     5000     10000     100000
vec   250ms    4s       16s       my laptop committed suicide
list  600ms    15s      63s       my laptop committed suicide
```

---

vec is fast than list so why my book says: **<< For performance reasons,
you wouldn't use insert and erase int the middle of 100000 element
vector; for that list (and map) are better.>>**
did i write my code in a wrong way?

Comment: This code does a quadratic time insertion sort.

Comment: can you explain me how you calculated this in order to avoid such things in the future?

Comment: The book is wrong, unless you're leaving out some context. A `list` is only faster when inserting *at a previously determined point*. If you need to determine that point for each insertion, they are often worse in a list than in a vector. (There's even a talk by Stroustrup online where he discusses this.)